# Need to fix this code working with google maps drawing

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to Google Maps API and I'm working with an external services called Random User Generator -> randomuser.me

I'm suppose to click on the button and this will draw a circle on the map.
The Random User Generator gives me a zipcode, then I use the google maps geocoder to get LatLng and then use the drawing circle option.

The problem is that nothing happens and I'm not getting any errors on the console.

Here's my code:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {        
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(16.4706001, -33.6728973),
          zoom:3,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

    <div id="button">
      <button id="loadbutton">Click to Load</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var randomuserURL = 'http://api.randomuser.me/';
var map;
var lat = '';
var lng = '';
var zipcode;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var circleLocations;
var circle;
var cityCircle;

var myButton = document.getElementById('loadbutton');
myButton.onclick = loadAJAX;


function loadAJAX () {
    $.ajax({
      url: randomuserURL,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        zipcode = data.results[0].user.location.zip;
        latlng();
      }
    });
}

function latlng () {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zipcode}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
             lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
             loadCircles(cityCircle);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}

function loadCircles () {
    var circleLocations = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    var circle = {
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        center: circleLocations,
        radius: 20
    };
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(circle);
}
```

Any clue?

Comment: Using `try` and `catch`: `ReferenceError: loadAJAX is not defined`

Comment: There are lots of errors in your code. loadAJAX undefined and latlng function has not a parameter but you are sending cityCircle paramter.. And an advise dont use global variables for everything.

Comment: I've deleted the parameters, it should still work but it still doesn't

Comment: "need to fix this code" questions are not welcome at SO. Post particular isolated problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of errors. As a favor, I merged your html and JS code together and got it to do the basics. Hopefully, you can work fro here. Things I changed:

1. Changed displaying the initial map to  jQuery load event.
2. Centered the map initially on Kansas City, US
3. Set a reasonable radius for displaying the circle (you were set at 20 meters).
4. Set the calling of loadAJAX() to a jQuery event on clicking on 'loadbutton'
5. Added displaying the zip code returned under the button.
6. Recentered the map each time to the current zip code.
7. Added CSS code to set the width/height of the map.

   $(function() {

   ```
   var mapOptions = {
         center: new google.maps.LatLng( 39.0997, -94.5786 ),
         zoom:3,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

   var randomuserURL = 'http://api.randomuser.me/';
   var map;
   var lat = '';
   var lng = '';
   var zipcode;
   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   var circleLocations;
   var circle;
   var cityCircle;

   $( "#loadbutton" ).click( function( event ) {
       loadAJAX();
   } );

   function loadAJAX () {
       $.ajax({
         url: randomuserURL,
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data){
           zipcode = data.results[0].user.location.zip;
           latlng();
         }
       });
   }



   function latlng () {
       div = document.getElementById( "zipcode" );
       div.innerHTML = "ZipCode: " + zipcode;
       geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zipcode}, function(results, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                loadCircles(cityCircle);
           } else {
               alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
           }
       });
   }

   function loadCircles () {
       var circleLocations = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
       var circle = {
           strokeColor: '#FF0000',
           strokeOpacity: 0.8,
           strokeWeight: 2,
           fillColor: '#FF0000',
           fillOpacity: 0.35,
           map: map,
           center: circleLocations,
           radius: 40000,
       };
       cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(circle);
       map.setCenter( circleLocations );
       map.setZoom( 6 );
   }
   ```

   });

   ## map-canvas

   {
       width: 500px;
       height: 500px;
   }

   ```
   <div id="map-canvas"></div>
   <div id="button">
     <button id="loadbutton">Click to Load</button>
   </div>
   <div id="zipcode"></div>
   ```

Comment: Hum, I am having problems getting all the code to show up as one code chunk? It's missing the HTML header part and the CSS code got partially cut off as well. Does somebody know how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `try` and `catch`, I found out `loadAJAX is not defined.`  This means that you have invalid syntax, and I found the source.

Replace

```
myButton.onclick = loadAJAX;
```

with

```
myButton.onclick = function()
{
    loadAJAX();
};
```

and on another note, your code isn't working because you are passing a parameter to a function that does not take parameters, the code is `loadCircles(cityCircle);`

If you're still wondering why it's not working, it's because you used the API almost entirely incorrectly.

Comment: @user3062745  If you want to fix your code up a bit, work off of [this](http://jsfiddle.net/368BY/)